# MongoDB/javascript Use an Array in an Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm making an assignment and I need an array in my database existing like this:

```
Questions [category : "Math", Question[questionID: 1, question:"What is 1+1", answer:"2"], category: "Math", Question[questionID: 2, question:"What is 2+2", answer:"4"]]
```

and so on. Now in Robo3T I can create a db like this
[image]

Now when I use mongoose, it doesn't create any placeholders whatsoever in the database. It stops at an array op Questions, with nothing in it. How can insert an entry in this array which looks like

[image]

The code I'm trying to run is the following:
[image]

The problem I'm having is that outside the function `randomQuestions` is empty so I can't begin to try and push it in the database. And within the function, I can't use await in combination with Quiz.updateOne. I think my error lies there. I tried pushing a random value into the array, which works fine. The output of the function(whats found in `randomQuestions` looks like this

[image]

Comment: Can you show how have you designed your Model?

Comment: @wak786 The schema looks like this. https://i.imgur.com/JIp0hQJ.png I tried removing the predefined questionID, question and answer and just have an empty array and push it in there, but this didnt do the trick either.

Comment: How are you pushing the new question to the array? The schema look like it should work so there must be something wrong with how you are pushing to the array using Mongoose. A code example would be helpful.

Comment: @saulmaldonado i added a picture of the piece of code itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you created the update query but haven't executed it.

Changing:

```js
Quiz.updateOne({ gamepin: req.params.gamepin },{ $push: { questions: randomQuestions } });
```

to:

```js
Quiz.updateOne({ gamepin: req.params.gamepin },{ $push: { questions: randomQuestions } }).exec();
```

Fixes your problem.

The queries are not called implicitly to allow you to manipulate and build the query by chaining on different operators.
You actually did this in your code for a different query.

```js
Questions.findOne()
  .skip(random)
  .exec(function(err, result){
  ...
});
```

You can also use the `await` to skip having to do this and execute the query immediately. This is the recommended way of executing queries.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did try to do the await method, but this gave me an error(can't find which). The code i previously had, came from another post on stack overflow. I did not know how the .exec works. I started this class in school 6 weeks ago, starting with basic javascript. Hence I'm still learning.
Thank you a lot tho! Your answer did help me in a way :)

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the code another way. Now it does work, but I still don't really understand what was wrong with the previous code.

````
expressApp.get("/quizzer/:gamepin/:category", async (req, res) => {
  let randomQuestions = [];
  let total = await Questions.countDocuments({ category: req.params.category });
  for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * total);
    question = await Questions.findOne().skip(random);
    if (randomQuestions[question]) {
      i--;
    } else {
      randomQuestions.push(question);
    }
  }
  await Quiz.updateOne(
    { gamepin: req.params.gamepin },
    { $push: { questions: randomQuestions } }
  );
  res.send("done");
});```
````